# Javascript :focus For Each Input

Tags: javascript, focus

```
$('input[type="text"]').on('focus',function(){ // When focus
    $(this).css('borderColor','#e89980');
    $(this).css('boxShadow','0 0 0 2px #e89980');
});
```

I need to make this so if you click on more then one input, the focus is only on that specific input and not all of the other ones with the type of text that have been clicked(focused).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just add a css class to the selected one. Then remove it on blur.

```
.active {
  borderColor: #e89980;
  boxShadow: 0 0 0 2px #e89980;
}
```

[quick demo](http://codepen.io/ryanjgill/pen/GgoPVB)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set them back after they aren't in the focus anymore (onblur function) 
Otherwise the effect of your focus function will still take effect.